# WP7 : Populating a ListBox depending on the input from another ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, listboxitem, listboxitems

I'm trying to add ListItems to a ListBox (ListBox3) depending on the selectedItem of another ListBox (ListBox1). The problem is , The Items aren't added to the Listbox.

Here's the code :

```
      private void createlist()
      {
        if (listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("EPL"))

        {
            ListBoxItem manchesterunited = new ListBoxItem();
            manchesterunited.Content = "Manchester United";
            listBox3.Items.Add(manchesterunited);
        }
     }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        createlist();
    }
```

createlist() does the changes and is called in the SelctionChanged() event of ListBox1.

New to C# and WP7 programming , any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the lists in your `viewmodel` and bind the `listbox` to a `list<>` in your viewmodel say `SelectedList`. When the user selects the item from `ListBox1` just change the value of SelectedList with the appropriate List and `Notify the property changed event`. And it will be done.!

Answer (score 0):

i think you program not run in mvvm structure.

make sure your logic is right. you can make a breakpoint at  the line
ListBoxItem manchesterunited = new ListBoxItem(); 
Ensure run those code in if code block.

the way add a control in a listbox is correct.